# How to include relative link in rmarkdown / distill

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, r-distill

I have a web site using rmarkdown and distill, and want to include a link to another page on the site.
I tried:

```
Some content on this topic and pointers to relevant literature will be provided under
![_Learning More_ for Chapter 7](learning_more.html).
```

But when I build the site, I get an image of the page, not a standard hyperlink.  What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Oh, that’s cool, I didn’t even know that was possible. You’ve used the syntax for image inclusion. Can you try again without the `!` in front of the link?

Comment: Ugh!, maybe that was the problem.